# Replace text in a file from another file

Tags: text-processing, scripting

Say I have a file called `before.txt` which reads:

```
1  
2  
3  
4
```

but want to replace the number `4` with a number (in order) from a text file called `after.txt`. How would I do so?

`after.txt` contains:

```
2743
3028
2850
1092
etc.
```

Could this be turned into a script as well? If so, I would like it to cycle through all the strings from `after.txt` in order, and replace the string `4` as said above.

Comment: Is "2743" the only content in `after.txt`?

Comment: No, there are multiple strings. If possible I would like the script to cycle through them all one at a time. (Thanks for the edit btw)

Comment: Please edit your question to include a sample of `after.txt` so people know exactly what they are dealing with.

Comment: So you want as many different result files as lines in `after.txt`? In other words, loop over each line as explained e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349827/how-do-i-iterate-through-lines-in-an-external-file-with-shell)?

Comment: Whats your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given these files:

```
cat before.txt 
1  
2  
3  
4
1  
1  
2  
3  
4
2  
3  
4

cat after.txt
2743
3028
2850
1092
```

And this little script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line"  == 4 ]]; then
        sed -n '1p' after.txt
        sed -i".bup" '1d' after.txt 
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi  
done < before.txt
```

I get this result:

```
./script.sh 
1
2
3
2743
1
1
2
3
3028
2
3
2850
```

I am sure there is an `awk` oneliner that can do this, but I don't speak `awk` fluently! Also, if you want to replace ("in place") the file `before.txt`, you will have to change the `sed` statements in the loop. Otherwise you can simply redirect `STDOUT` to a new file. I choose to print everything to `STDOUT` in this example for easy viewing.

---

Tested under **OS X 10.11.6** and BSD `sed`

Comment: No problem. But please read the comments. Next time, it would be appreciated if you posted your desired **output**, as well as a sample of what **you** have tried. Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/^4$/&&getline<"after.txt"||1' before.txt
```

If the current record `$0` is exactly the text `4`, then get the next line from `after.txt`. If that is successful, it becomes `$0` and `getline` returns 1, so the expression is true and the default `{print}` action is triggered.

If the record is not `4`, or getline returns `0` at the `EOF` of `after.txt`, the `||1` ensures that we still print the current record. `$0` is unmodified if reading `after.txt` fails.

If `getline` fails with a `-1`, we still print `$0`, since that is a nonzero return code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in awk ?

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{Arr[NR]=$0;next}{if($0==4){i++;print Arr[i]}else{print}}' after.txt before.txt
1
2
3
2743
1
1
2
3
3028
2
3
2850
```